# Align vertically in a link

Tags: html, hyperlink, alignment, vertical-alignment

```css
    h1, div {
      font-family:"Sans-Serif";
      color:#FFF;
    }
    h1{
      text-align:center;
      font-size:3em;
    }
    div {
      text-align:justify;
      position:50%;
      font-size:1.5em;
    }

    .description {
      text-decoration:none;
      color:#AAA;
    }
    .description:hover {color:#888;}
    .description:active {color:#555;}

    nav {
      text-align:center;
      vertical-align:middle;
      margin:50px 0px;
    }
    .nav {
      display:inline-block;

      text-decoration:none;
      color:white;
      font-family:"Sans-Serif";
      font-size:1.5em;
      font-weight:bold;

      width:20%;
      height:60px;

      margin:35px 60px;
      padding:10px;
      text-align:center;

      background-color:#05F;
      border:2px dashed;
      border-color:white;
      border-radius:15px;
    }
    img {
      width:50px;
      height:50px;
      margin:10px;
    }
```

```html
<body style="background-color:#000;">

  <h1>Score Calculator</h1>

  <br />

  <div>
    It works as <a class="description" href="https://hashcodejudge.withgoogle.com/" target="_blank">Google's Hash Code 2020 Judge System</a>: you can calculate your score without creating a whole submission or you can test your files befone sending it to <a class="description" href="https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/hashcode" target="_blank">Google</a>.
  </div>

  <br />

  <nav>
    <a class="nav" href="http://www.mediafire.com/folder/pyhaewgizjimb"><img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/144384/zip.svg" /><Full folder</a>
    <a class="nav" href="http://www.mediafire.com/file/em25u2rbxvbxuhx"><img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/144384/zip.svg" /><ZIP archive</a><br />
    <a class="nav" href="http://www.mediafire.com/file/tjftl0obi9jeo3r"><img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/144384/zip.svg" /><Submission Calculator x86</a>
    <a class="nav" href="http://www.mediafire.com/file/r3bcd0ntuv8bwn6"><img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/144384/zip.svg" /><Submission Calculator x64</a><br />
    <a class="nav" href="http://www.mediafire.com/file/drwp86tv26u1fs2"><img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/144384/zip.svg" /><File Calculator x86</a>
    <a class="nav" href="http://www.mediafire.com/file/2ogmhjbkrry6mkp"><img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/144384/zip.svg" /><File Calculator x64</a><br />
    <a class="nav" href="http://www.mediafire.com/file/9wkxoyz6nuetw4x"><img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/144384/zip.svg" /><Submission Calculator Source Code</a>
    <a class="nav" href="http://www.mediafire.com/file/gm4ngpnq3vz9d19"><img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/144384/zip.svg" /><File Calculator Source Code</a><br />
  </nav>

<body>
```

..................................................................

How can I vertically align in the center the text inside my links? `vertical-align` doesn't work.

I also tried to put it in a  but nothing changed.
Do I have to edit the link or the container?

(Sorry if it is a stupid question but I a beginner in html/css)

Comment: Try using a `line-height` that is equal to the elements' `height`, that usually works... And make sure `font-size` and `line-height` fit within the `height` and `padding` too.

Comment: Would you provide an image of result to show what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is multiple ways to achieve this. check attach snippet below:..

1. **Just give margin `5px` instead of `10px` in img tag**

```css
    h1, div {
      font-family:"Sans-Serif";
      color:#FFF;
    }
    h1{
      text-align:center;
      font-size:3em;
    }
    div {
      text-align:justify;
      position:50%;
      font-size:1.5em;
    }

    .description {
      text-decoration:none;
      color:#AAA;
    }
    .description:hover {color:#888;}
    .description:active {color:#555;}

    nav {
      text-align:center;
      vertical-align:middle;
      margin:50px 0px;
    }
    .nav {
      display:inline-block;

      text-decoration:none;
      color:white;
      font-family:"Sans-Serif";
      font-size:1.5em;
      font-weight:bold;

      width:20%;
      height:60px;

      margin:35px 60px;
      padding:10px;
      text-align:center;

      background-color:#05F;
      border:2px dashed;
      border-color:white;
      border-radius:15px;
    }
    img {
      width:50px;
      height:50px;
      margin:5px;
    }
```

```html
<body style="background-color:#000;">

  <h1>Score Calculator</h1>

  <br />

  <div>
    It works as <a class="description" href="https://hashcodejudge.withgoogle.com/" target="_blank">Google's Hash Code 2020 Judge System</a>: you can calculate your score without creating a whole submission or you can test your files befone sending it to <a class="description" href="https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/hashcode" target="_blank">Google</a>.
  </div>

  <br />

  <nav>
    <a class="nav" href="http://www.mediafire.com/folder/pyhaewgizjimb"><img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/144384/zip.svg" /><Full folder</a>
    <a class="nav" href="http://www.mediafire.com/file/em25u2rbxvbxuhx"><img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/144384/zip.svg" /><ZIP archive</a><br />
    <a class="nav" href="http://www.mediafire.com/file/tjftl0obi9jeo3r"><img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/144384/zip.svg" /><Submission Calculator x86</a>
    <a class="nav" href="http://www.mediafire.com/file/r3bcd0ntuv8bwn6"><img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/144384/zip.svg" /><Submission Calculator x64</a><br />
    <a class="nav" href="http://www.mediafire.com/file/drwp86tv26u1fs2"><img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/144384/zip.svg" /><File Calculator x86</a>
    <a class="nav" href="http://www.mediafire.com/file/2ogmhjbkrry6mkp"><img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/144384/zip.svg" /><File Calculator x64</a><br />
    <a class="nav" href="http://www.mediafire.com/file/9wkxoyz6nuetw4x"><img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/144384/zip.svg" /><Submission Calculator Source Code</a>
    <a class="nav" href="http://www.mediafire.com/file/gm4ngpnq3vz9d19"><img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/144384/zip.svg" /><File Calculator Source Code</a><br />
  </nav>

<body>
```

**2. You can achieve this via `flex`:**

```css
h1, div {
      font-family:"Sans-Serif";
      color:#FFF;
    }
    h1{
      text-align:center;
      font-size:3em;
    }
    div {
      text-align:justify;
      position:50%;
      font-size:1.5em;
    }

    .description {
      text-decoration:none;
      color:#AAA;
    }
    .description:hover {color:#888;}
    .description:active {color:#555;}

    nav {
      text-align:center;
      vertical-align:middle;
      margin:50px 0px;
    }
    .nav {
      display:flex;
      float: left;
      text-decoration:none;
      color:white;
      font-family:"Sans-Serif";
      font-size:1.5em;
      font-weight:bold;

      width:20%;
      height:60px;

      margin:35px 60px;
      padding:10px;
      text-align:center;

      background-color:#05F;
      border:2px dashed;
      border-color:white;
      border-radius:15px;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    img {
      width:50px;
      height:50px;
    }
```

```html
<body style="background-color:#000;">

  <h1>Score Calculator</h1>

  <br />

  <div>
    It works as <a class="description" href="https://hashcodejudge.withgoogle.com/" target="_blank">Google's Hash Code 2020 Judge System</a>: you can calculate your score without creating a whole submission or you can test your files befone sending it to <a class="description" href="https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/hashcode" target="_blank">Google</a>.
  </div>

  <br />

  <nav>
    <a class="nav" href="http://www.mediafire.com/folder/pyhaewgizjimb"><img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/144384/zip.svg" /><Full folder</a>
    <a class="nav" href="http://www.mediafire.com/file/em25u2rbxvbxuhx"><img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/144384/zip.svg" /><ZIP archive</a><br />
    <a class="nav" href="http://www.mediafire.com/file/tjftl0obi9jeo3r"><img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/144384/zip.svg" /><Submission Calculator x86</a>
    <a class="nav" href="http://www.mediafire.com/file/r3bcd0ntuv8bwn6"><img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/144384/zip.svg" /><Submission Calculator x64</a><br />
    <a class="nav" href="http://www.mediafire.com/file/drwp86tv26u1fs2"><img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/144384/zip.svg" /><File Calculator x86</a>
    <a class="nav" href="http://www.mediafire.com/file/2ogmhjbkrry6mkp"><img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/144384/zip.svg" /><File Calculator x64</a><br />
    <a class="nav" href="http://www.mediafire.com/file/9wkxoyz6nuetw4x"><img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/144384/zip.svg" /><Submission Calculator Source Code</a>
    <a class="nav" href="http://www.mediafire.com/file/gm4ngpnq3vz9d19"><img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/144384/zip.svg" /><File Calculator Source Code</a><br />
  </nav>

<body>
```

Comment: Thank you, it was not perfect (links had been aligned into 3 columns) but it helped a lot to achieve my goal